# ChatGPT $20/month vs. ChatGPT API

Tags: chatgpt

I am curious if there is any difference between (A) accessing ChatGPT4 via their web page and \$20/month subscription on the one hand, or (B) via an application like MacGPT with their paid API key.

I've used (B) and no matter how much I use it I don't get charged more than \$5 or maybe \$10 per month.

Does (A) have any advantages that anyone knows about?

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it seems to be about specific software/APIs. It has little or nothing to do with theoretical aspects of AI. For more info about our on-topic page, see https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I didn't realize that this was just for theoretical ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChatGPT Plus (the $20/month offering) gives you access to GPT4. The API currently gives access to older models (from what I know). I have tried the davinci model via the API and to me it seems to be inferior to ChatGPT(v3.5), so it should be also inferior to GPT-4.

This is what MacGPT's FAQ says though:

"I added my API key and want to use GPT-4 but I get an error.
Currently the GPT-4 API is only available through the API after signing up for a waiting list. Please sign up through the OpenAI website and you should have access in a few days. Sign up here."

So if you join the whitelist and then get access to GPT-4 via API it should be the same as using ChatGPT Plus.